# Conditional validations in Spring

Tags: spring, validation, conditional-statements

I have a form which contain some `radio` button and `check-boxes`. Whenever user selects/deselects a `radio button` or `check-box` few other input fields are enabled/disabled.
I want to add **validation only for fields which are enabled when user submits the form**. Fields which are disabled at the time of submission should not be considered for validation.

I don't want to add this in client side validation.Is there any better /easy way to implement conditional validation in Spring 3.0 instead of adding multiple `if` in validator ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When fields are disabled they are transferred to controller as `null`. I wanted to add a validation which will allow either `null` i.e disabled field or `not blank` field i.e. enabled but empty field.
So I created a custom annotation `NotBlankOrNull` which will allow `null` and non empty strings also it takes care of blank spaces.
Here is my Annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { NotBlankOrNullValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NotBlankOrNull {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlankOrNull.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator class

```
public class NotBlankOrNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotBlankOrNull, String> {

    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return true;
        }
        return s.trim().length() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotBlankOrNull constraint) {

    }
}
```

I have also updated more details on my [site](http://www.ajinkyaparakh.com/2012/02/creating-custom-constraint-annotation.html).

Answer (score 14):

If you use JSR 303 Bean validation then you can use [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) (`groups`) for this.

Assume you have this user input, containing two sections.
The two booleans indicating if the sections are enabled or disabled. (Of course you can use more useful annotations than `@NotNull`)

```
public class UserInput {
   boolean sectionAEnabled;
   boolean sectionBEnabled;

   @NotNull(groups=SectionA.class)
   String someSectionAInput;

   @NotNull(groups=SectionA.class)
   String someOtherSectionAInput;

   @NotNull(groups=SectionB.class)
   String someSectionBInput;

   Getter and Setter
}
```

You need two Interfaces for the groups. They work only as marker.

```
public interface SectionA{}

public interface SectionB{}
```

**[Since Spring 3.1](http://blog.goyello.com/2011/12/16/enhancements-spring-mvc31/)**  you can use the Spring `@Validated` annotation (instead of `@Validate`) in your controller method to trigger the validation:

```
@RequestMapping...
public void controllerMethod(
         @Validated({SectionGroupA.class}) UserInput userInput, 
         BindingResult binding, ...){...}
```

**Before Spring 3.1** there was no way to specify the validation group that should been used for validation (because `@Validated` does not exist and `@Validate` does not have a group attribute), so you need to start the validation by hand written code: This an an example how to trigger the validation in dependence to witch section is enabled in Spring 3.0.

```
@RequestMapping...
public void controllerMethod(UserInput userInput,...){

  ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
  Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

  List<Class<?>> groups = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
  groups.add(javax.validation.groups.Default.class); //Always validate default
  if (userInput.isSectionAEnabled) {
     groups.add(SectionA.class);
  }
  if (userInput.isSectionBEnabled) {
     groups.add(SectionB.class);
  }
  Set<ConstraintViolation<UserInput>> validationResult =
     validator.validate(userInput,  groups.toArray(new Class[0]));

  if(validationResult.isEmpty()) {
     ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
}
```

*(BTW: For the Spring 3.0 solution, it is also possible to let Spring inject the validator:*

```
@Inject javax.validation.Validator validator

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
       <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

*)*

Comment: Looks like a really good suggestion. Just wondering how to apply this to fields present in DTO. I have few fields which are not present in bean/domain objecct but present on DTO and I want to add validations for them also.

Comment: You can put this javax.validation anntoation (NotNull,...) on fields of very class, Entity DTO,...   In the example above, UserInput should be a DTO