# Validate accept Headers in spring

Tags: java, spring, api, http-headers

How can I validate the accept headers in spring and return a custom message if the accept header is not application/json. Currently I am doing it this way(below) but I am wondering if there is another way of doing this?

I know I can make custom exceptions and throw the exception based on what went wrong but is there a different way of doing this?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> get(final HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    String acceptString = httpEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("Accept");

    if (acceptString == null || acceptString.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("empty accept header", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if ((MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).equalsIgnoreCase(acceptString)) {
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Not valid accept value", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `@Getmapping` you can add `headers="Accept=application/json"` this way your method will only handle calls with that header type.

You can then add a method which processes all the calls that are ignored by your specific AcceptHeader method. This way you only need one method to validate the headers.

You can also write a custom validator and use anotation to add this to your method like here:
[conditional validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257673/conditional-validations-in-spring)