# Disable validation annotation when filtering with Jackson @JsonView

Tags: java, spring, validation, json-view

I have the same form that displays more or less fields depending on the user's role. So I use [@JsonView](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-role-filter-json#how-to-integrate) to hide/ignore the fields that are not related to the current user's role. But the validation is still enabled and the `@NotNull` rule is triggered.

```
@JsonView({View.Admin.class, View.Tech.class})
@NotNull
private String name;
```

I would like to find a way to enable or disable some validation annotations for example when the user's role is not administrator.

Is it possible to use these view (`View.Admin.class` / `View.Tech.class`) as a group for validation please?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257673/conditional-validations-in-spring

Comment: I think "validation groups" offers the same functionality (for validation) as "json views" (for json;)

Comment: @xerx593 Yes, but I can't use my views as groups: `groups = { View.Admin.class, View.Tech.class }`

Comment: @RafaelGuillen I looked at it but I have to pass the group in @Validated but now I want it to be dynamic depending on my user's role, that's my problem. I also looked at using `@GroupSequenceProvider`, but I can't @Autowired my user in the custom provider :/

Answer (score -1):

use @JsonIgnore may help you to achieve,because it will ignore the column and validation annotation as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you add a little more context please? I'm not sure I understand how to use it with the`@JsonView` that already takes into account my roles

Comment: when we create multiple related table with bidirectional relationship, in that case when we fetch column data and we want from parent table, we use  @jsonIgnore for getting data through parent table

Comment: I think in this situation we also ignore the column by using @JsonIgnore annotation

Comment: I hope it will help you in resolving your problem